# What is the difference between * and *.* while copying?

Tags: shell, shell-script, command-line, cp

What is the difference between following 2 commands?

```
cp -rp /dir1/*.* /dir2/
cp -rp /dir1/* /dir2/
```

Comment: Even though both answers are correct, I think there is one thing to be noted. Hidden files (files that start with `.` like `.bashrc`) are not copied with any of those commands. To copy those files you should explicitly indicate that with `.*` so, to copy all files (including hidden ones) the command would be `cp -rp /dir1/.* /dir1/* /dir2/`

Comment: In short, `*.*` is the MS-DOS/Windows way of doing it, while `*` is the UNIX/Linux way.  In Unix suffix (file-ending, the part after the `.` - like `.txt` or `.jpg`) is optional...  In MS-DOS the `.` (dot) and suffix was required, so to match all files, one used `*.*` - while to match all text-files, one would use `*.txt`.

Comment: @BaardKopperud suffix wasn't required, there could be files with name like `FILENAME` or even `FILE`.

Comment: @Ruslan but `*.*` in DOS still matches files named `FILENAME` or `FILE`, because the name is 'really' `FILENAME.` or `FILE.` (with an empty extension).  In Unix, the name is 'really' `FILENAME` or `FILE`, so `*.*` won't match.

Comment: @Ruslan It was required on actual DOS, not required anymore on windows. Back in the _old days_, a single `*` would only match `FILE`, and _not_ `FILE.TXT`.

Comment: @Random832 dunno what version of DOS you mean, I successfully created files without suffixes when running DOS created by WinXP "make a bootable floppy" feature. At least Volkov Commander was able to make such files.

Comment: @Ruslan Sorry, I think we miscommunicated. I mean that you need to include an extension in the wildcard `*.*` in order to match files that have extensions. The wildcard `*` in old versions of DOS would _only_ match files without extensions, and would not match files that do have them.

Comment: @Random832 yeah, with this I do agree.

Comment: @Random832: Actually, that's not quite correct.  In old 8.3 DOS, `*` and `*.*` were [entirely the same](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/12/17/6785519.aspx).  But 8.3 was weird in many other ways and doesn't properly compare to modern filenames.

Comment: @Kevin The user "Goplat" does point out in the comments a number of differences between his rules (which are based on an analysis of CP/M) and the real-world behavior of DOS, including this one. And really otherwise why would anyone type `*.*`?

Comment: @Random832: Fair enough.  I was just trying to point out that 8.3 was *weird* and you can't reason about it the way you do long filenames.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`*.*` only matches filenames with a dot in the middle or at the end. For example:

```
abc.jpg
def.
```

`*` matches the filenames above, plus the names which don't have a dot at all. for example:

```
data
```

Comment: Maybe also note that the anti-idiom `*.*` used to be the correct way to match all files on MS-DOS back in the day of 8+3 filenames.  In MS-DOS, the dot is mandatory (albeit implicit on files which do not have an extension).

Comment: `*.*` also matches files with a dot at the beginning, eg `.config`.

Comment: @Mark, No, I don't think so. unless you have dotglob on.

Comment: Huh, I never realized that `*.*` matches `foo.` but not `.foo`.  That asymmetry is terrible.

Comment: @jamesdlin, from bash manual: When a pattern is used for filename expansion, the character ‘.’ at the start of a filename or immediately following a slash must be matched explicitly, unless the shell option dotglob is set.

Comment: @DavidDai That doesn't actually answer it. It's possible to parse `.dotfile` with `*.*` where the first `*` matches nothing, the `.` explicitly matches the `.`, and the second `*` matches `dotfile`. This would be consistent with the bash manual too. All the bash manual says is that plain `*` *won't* match `.dotfile` unless `dotglob` is set. (Of course what bash *actually* does is require a `.` in the pattern to be right at the start of a path component, which is exactly how you interpret the manual.)

Comment: @jamesdlin. Since the 1st day of Unix (circa 1969), directory entries starting with a dot were considered _hidden_.  Originally this was needed to skip the `.` (current directory) and `..` (parent directory) entries which always exist in any directory (even empty dirs).  Ritchie and Thompson later considered it to be a useful feature to hide (by default) all the `.*rc` config files and added an explicit `-a` option to `ls` to display all these (leading-dot) "hidden" entries.  So this is not very surprising knowing Unix history.  A leading dot in Unix has been special since "forever".

Answer (score 12):

Suppose your have following files in `/dir1`:

```
foobar  
foo.bar  
fo.ba  
foo1.bar2  
foobar1  
foobar2
```

---

```
cp -rp /dir1/*.* /dir2/
```

This command will copy only the following files:

```
foo.bar  
fo.ba  
foo1.bar2
```

---

```
cp -rp /dir1/* /dir2/
```

This will copy all the files in `/dir1`

The condition applies to the subdirectories in `/dir1` as well..